# Try to Intersect JSON Array

Tags: json, node.js

I need to Intersect my Query Result. After intersection the data I want to use it in my page.

This is my Data : (I store the data in variable "hasilget")

```
[
    {
        "_id" : "2017-05-22",
        "kamar" : [
            [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("570f5095c8dbf1045d7fe9b3"),
                    "namkam" : "VIP ONE",
                    "idtipe" : ObjectId("57023e5e36b35501f17ea5c6")
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("570f509dc8dbf1035d7fe9b5"),
                    "namkam" : "VIP TWO",
                    "idtipe" : ObjectId("57023e5e36b37601f17ea5c6")
                }
            ]
        ]
    },

    {
        "_id" : "2017-05-23",
        "kamar" : [
            [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("570f5095c8dbf1045d7fe9b3"),
                    "namkam" : "VIP ONE",
                    "idtipe" : ObjectId("57023e5e36b35501f17ea5c6")
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

I have try Use "Array-Intersection" from NPM.

```
var inter = intersection(hasilget);
console.log("Hasil "+JSON.stringify(inter));
```

But The Problem is the output is Still Originally Result. The Intersection Function is not working.

Please guide me.

Comment: Why are you stringifying the input and then doing nothing with the result? Why are you printing out the original object, instead of the result of calling  `intersection`? Do you realize that when printing to the console the console may represent objects as `[object Object]` when converted to a string as your are doing? To start off, try `console.log(hasilget)`, or `console.dir(hasilget)`.

Comment: I am sorry I give wrong code.. I have edited. That's my code... My Problem is Why the "Intersection is not working"? It's Still Show The Original Result.

Comment: What do you expect array intersection to do? What are you trying to intersect with what? What do you think intersection means? You are giving it one array, so the result will be the input (although exact duplicates would be removed). If you want to take the difference of multiple arrays, you need to pass it multiple arrays.

Comment: Could you please describe what values are you expecting as the result of the intersection?

Comment: The Result Should be :

{
                    "_id" : ObjectId("570f5095c8dbf1045d7fe9b3"),
                    "namkam" : "VIP ONE",
                    "idtipe" : ObjectId("57023e5e36b35501f17ea5c6") }